# Change icon on Mate menubar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop, desktop-customization

How can I change the Ubuntu Mate logo icon to a custom icon by the applications menu in Ubuntu Mate without changing the theme?

[image: Menubar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately for this menu it is only possible to do manually with the dconf-editor.

1. install dconf-editor
   `sudo apt install dconf-editor`
2. go to  `org > mate > panel > menubar`
3. change default icon-name to your new icon name

if you want to have a custom icon, copy the .svg image to /usr/share/icons/apps/image.svg
replace image with the image title of course...

https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/how-i-can-change-main-menu-icon/9884/3

PS: Using Manjaro you simply have to put your prefered icon to `~/.icons/logo-manjaro.svg`

PSS: I found the name of the menu's icon using [Gtk Inspector](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK/Inspector)

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time customizing icon sets in MATE desktops. The menu icon is, as the above post says, usually in /usr/share/icons/[icon set]/scalable/apps, under the name start-here.svg... But this will vary depending on distro and icon set.

A partial map, as it is in the Debians I have seen, is below. In addition, MATE power manager icons can also be found in /usr/share/mate-power-manager/icons, which fooled me for some time.

```
##actions/symbolic - system shutd0wn, log-out and lock. 
##apps - Application including for core system applications like file-manager and terminal, and network manager. 
##devices - Hardware devices, including the computer icon, harddisks and removable media.
##categories/start-menu - The panel menu and its categories. 
##mimetypes - All the file types. 
##places - User-folders, desktop shortcut icon, and the file-manager icons for user, trash, network. 
##status - Audio, battery and network connectivity, though connecting animations are stored in apps. 


##Panel Menu
start-here.svg # Panel menu button (/apps/scalable/).
system-shut-down.svg # Menu shut down button (/actions/symbolic/).
system-log-out.svg # Menu log out icon (/actions/symbolic/).
system-lock-screen.svg # Menu lock screen icon (/actions/symbolic/).
applications-accessories.svg # Menu accessories (/categories/start-menu/).
applications-internet.svg # (/categories/start-menu/).
applications-science.svg # (/categories/start-menu/).
applications-graphics.svg # (/categories/start-menu/).
applications-office.svg # (/categories/start-menu/).
applications-multimedia.svg # (/categories/start-menu/).

##Desktop and Caja Left-Pane
computer.svg # Computer or system icon (/devices/hardware). 
drive-harddisk.svg # File system icon (/devices/hardware/).
folder-network.svg # Browse network icon (/places/user-folders-small/).
desktop.svg # Desktop shortcut and panel applet (/places/user-folders/).
desktop2.svg # Desktop shortcut and panel applet (/places/user-folders-small/).
folder.svg # Principle folder icon (/places/user-folders/).
folder2.svg # Principle folder icon (/places/user-folders-small/).
user-home.svg # User icon (/places/user-folders-small/).
user-home2.svg # Desktop user folder (/places/user-folders/).
user-trash.svg # User trash icon (/places/user-folders/).


##Panel
system-file-manager.svg # Caja file manager icon (/apps/scalable/).
accessories-text-editor.svg # Pluma text editor icon (/apps/scalable/).
utilities-terminal.svg # Terminal icon (/apps/scalable/).
```